# Is it possible to receive email at AzureAppService: [username]@[appserviceUrl domain]?

Tags: azure, email, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.Net Core MVC  app deployed to Azure as an AppService.
Is it possible to set up to receive email at an address like:
[someusername]@[appservicename].azurewebsites.net?

I tried to set up a company website on Yelp and I can't remember what I did but now my Yelp business page wants me to plug in a username for
"[username]@[AppserviceICreatedWithMyCompanyName].azurewebsites.net" so it can send me an email to verify.

Comment: you want to create an email for you using app serivce?

Comment: No. There has to be an actual mail service running an bound to that domain, and you can't do that via an App Service. More specifically, there must be an MX record in the DNS, which Microsoft doesn't give you. Attach your own custom domain or use a different method to verify the site with Yelp. They should give you an option like uploading a file or adding a meta tag, for example.